# Find tables that are not in another database sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two different databases and have 122 tables in database1 and 125 tables in database2(with same table names in both the databases). one of the table in database1(tblusers) have an extra column compared to the table (tblusers) in database2. 
Now how do i find the extra tables that are in database2 and also find the extra column in the table. (By comparing two tables in two databases).

Msforeachdb would be great, else a normal query.

Comment: Which database are you using? mysql <> sql server

Comment: Sql server database.

Comment: Why would you use msforeachdb here? You said you are trying to compare tables in two known databases. You could compare sys.tables and sys.columns with queries against both databases. Another option would be using redgate's sql compare. It does all that plus check indexes and such.

Comment: If you've got Visual Studio you can also do a Schema Compare.

Comment: @Sean Lange, can i have any query that gives me tables in db that are not in the another database? like in the above scenario, can i have a query to find the 3 extra tables from database2? 
Sorry that Am not aware if redgates sql compare tool.

Comment: Sure there is nothing magical about this. You would pull table names from sys.tables on db1 and left join to sys.tables on db2 where db2.name is null. Or any of the other standard methods for finding missing rows. Or you could even do a full outer join to get all tables from both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For clarity and the benefit of the community. The answer as posted in the comments by Sean Lange on the OP is:

> Why would you use msforeachdb here? You said you are trying to compare
>   tables in two known databases. You could compare sys.tables and
>   sys.columns with queries against both databases. Another option would
>   be using redgate's sql compare. It does all that plus check indexes
>   and such.

Comment: This worked for me :) 

`SELECT  Table_Name from 
[databasename1].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME not in
(Select  Table_Name from [databasename2].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES )
`